# EF 4 Navigation Properties Question

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, navigation-properties

Suppose I had TableA with 2 relationship references to TableB, where TableB is the primary key (let's say it has a PrimaryBKey and SecondaryBKey columns as the FK names in TableA).  So I have entity:

```
TableA
    public TableB TableB { .. } 
    public TableB TableB1 { .. }
```

Is there any documentation on how EF derives the naming scheme, and can it change?  I have developers telling me that when they regen a table, it's changing the ordering of relationships.  What I mean  by that is that originally the entity was mapped in this way:

```
PrimaryBKey = TableB1
SecondaryBKey = TableB
```

But they said that it was switched later on to:

```
PrimaryBKey = TableB
SecondaryBKey = TableB1
```

Is that even possible?  I can't quite find any documentation on the naming scheme to verify this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused what your asking are trying to create a composite key reference or trying to reference the tale in 2 different ways?

Comment: No I'm asking a question specific to the code generation of the relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three documents will have what you are looking for, specifically the first two:

- [Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161541%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) (Scroll to Relationship Convention)
- [Configuring Relationships with Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843%28v=VS.103%29.aspx)
- [Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28v=VS.103%29.aspx)